# PHP: CURL return empty data

Tags: php, curl, https, instagram

This is my code but not work and return empty data

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/xxx/?__a=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 900);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

If i change `CURLOPT_URL` to `http://google.com` work fine, but for `instagram` not work

How i can fix it ?

Comment: Change `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true` and notice that server returns `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`. You may see same code when you visit this page manually with your browser.

Comment: Maybe you should try file_get_contents() . $result = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/xxx/?__a=1'); print_r($result);

Comment: @user1597430 i get this error `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 x-robots-tag: noindex Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie Content-Language: en Date: Sun, 04 Nov 2018 10:09:13 GMT Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=60 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN content-security-policy: report-uri https://www.instagram.com/security/csp_report/; default-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; img-src https: data: blob:; font-src https: data:; media-src 'self' blob: ...`

Comment: @SreekanthMK not work for me

Comment: Once again: code works fine, your browser will show you same error. Check the url.

Comment: @user1597430 but not show anything. i use in browser and work fine. but in curl not work!

Comment: Open the page in the incognito mode. Seems that you can open this page because you are logged in.

Comment: @user1597430 OK!. first i have to login to instagram and after get data ?

Comment: You need to be authenticated to be able to access that URL. You're probably already logged in with your browser while your web server isn't. Check instagrams API documentation on how to authenticate.